# how to align center the list elements in a modal

Tags: html, css

I want to align the list content centered in HTML for the code below. When the screen size is smaller it looks good but when it is wide it is not centered. I tried to make it responsive by using viewport but then modal showed up before it is triggered. Thank you for the help.

```css
/* Modal Window */
.modal {
  display: none;        /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed;      /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1;           /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px;   /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;          /* Full width */
  height: 100%;         /* Full height */
  overflow: auto;       /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0, 0, 0);         /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);   /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 50%;
  height: 50%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}
.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #02ccba;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
}
.modal-body {
  padding: 2px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 50%;
  /*margin-right: 30px;*/
}
.modal-list {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  width: 200px;
}
#modal-body-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  text-align: left;
}
.list-item {
  font-weight: bold;
}
#list-star {
  text-align: center;
}
#playAgainButton {
  -webkit-border-radius: 34;
  -moz-border-radius: 34;
  border-radius: 34px;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  margin: 20px 0;
  border: solid #02ccbb 4px;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- Modal Content -->
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <span class="close">&times;</span>
    <h2>CONGRATULATIONS!</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    <ul id="modal-body-list">
      <li class="modal-list">
        <span class="list-item">Moves:</span>
        <span id="list-moves"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="modal-list">
        <span class="list-item">Time:</span>
        <span id="list-time"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="modal-list">
        <span class="list-item">Star:</span>
        <span id="list-star"></span>
      </li>
      <li class="modal-list">
        <button id="playAgainButton">Play Again</button>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

PS: The code above is from w3schools. I just modified it.

Comment: It's not quite clear what you're aiming for, but did you read this guide: https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/

Answer (score 0):

Try this hope this solution help.

```css
 .modal {
    display: none; /* Hidden by default */
    position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
    z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
    padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%; /* Full width */
    height: 100%; /* Full height */
    overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
    background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
    position: relative;
    background-color: #fefefe;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    border: 1px solid #888;
    width: 50%;
    box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
    -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
    animation-name: animatetop;
    animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
    color: white;
    float: right;
    font-size: 28px;
    font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
    color: #000;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
    padding: 2px 16px;
    background-color: #02ccba;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
}

.modal-body {
    text-align: center;
    width:100%;
    /*margin-right: 30px;*/
}

.modal-list {
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;

}

#modal-body-list {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.list-item {
    font-weight: bold;
}

#list-star {
  text-align: center;
}

#playAgainButton {
    -webkit-border-radius: 34;
    -moz-border-radius: 34;
    border-radius: 34px;
    font-family: Arial;
    color: #000000;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding: 5px 10px;
    margin: 20px 0;
    border: solid #02ccbb 4px;
    text-decoration: none;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>CONGRATULATIONS!</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <ul id="modal-body-list">
        <li class="modal-list">
          <span class="list-item">Moves:</span>
          <span id="list-moves"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="modal-list">
          <span class="list-item">Time:</span>
          <span id="list-time"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="modal-list">
          <span class="list-item">Star:</span>
          <span id="list-star"></span>
        </li>
        <li class="modal-list">
          <button id="playAgainButton">Play Again</button>
        </li>
      </ul>

    </div>
  </div>
```